# NoSuchMethodError For SLF4J

Tags: java, spring, log4j, slf4j

I'm trying to build an application in Spring using sfl4j and log4j. I read and done all the instructions about removing the commons-logging from the spring-context. However I keep on getting the same error:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListenerjava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.info(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:159)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:273)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:536)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1462)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:792)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:860)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:357)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Here's my pom.xml:

`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>            
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>           
        <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
    </dependency>                        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>             
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>                        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>         
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>paypal.payflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>payflow-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>4.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>                   
    </dependency>      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>            
    </dependency>                                              
</dependencies>`
```

Can someone please help? I've spent days trying to figure this out.

Comment: This isn't your current problem, but you should add `<scope>test</scope>` to the junit dependency.  Can you check whether you have a transitive dependency on `log4j` with runtime scope and one on `slf4j-api` with compile scope?

Comment: both log4j and slf4j-api have a compile scope. I tried changing those to runtime but when I changed to this scope on spring-context dependency, classes using that dependency threw errors so I left everything to compile.

Comment: The scope issues depend on what exactly is in your source code; if you and the library writers are disciplined, you only need log4j at runtime.  Then I just don't know.  `junit` should almost always be test scope, however, which doesn't help your main problem.

Comment: Which ${slf4jVersion} do you use?

Comment: It seems dependency mismatch problem. Please **provide versions of all of your major jars like spring and hibernate. What server you are using?**

Answer (score 1):

@Solubris, 
you gave me the right pointers. It didn't initially work, as per my reply to your post, because I didn't delete any related old jars of slf4j.version still in the lib folder. So when I deleted all those duplicated libraries, the web application deploys just fine.

For any one encountering the same issue, please follow Solubris solution and then... make sure to check your lib folder and delete any slf4j related jars having older versions. I hope this can save someone countless hours of wondering and turning to madness!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to resolve problem is to include source files for your log4j libraries and research invocation chaining.

- Be sure log4j and jcl-over-slf4j successfully deployed on the Tomcat.
- Use [grepcode for log4j-api](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.2/org/slf4j/spi/LocationAwareLogger.java/) and [jcl-over-lsf4j](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.2/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java/) to analyze problem root and resolve version compatibility.
- Be sure you have no conflicts in your classpath. Use next snippet to be sure you loaded classes from libraries jars:

example:

```
    Class klass = String.class;
    URL location = klass.getResource('/'+klass.getName().replace('.', '/')+".class");
```

will print this type of the string:

```
    jar:file:/Users/taky/.gradle/caches/artifacts-14/filestore/com.google.inject/guice/3.0/jar/9d84f15fe35e2c716a02979fb62f50a29f38aefa/guice-3.0.jar!/com/google/inject/internal/InjectorImpl.class
```

Comment: both jar are successfully deployed on tomcat and and both use the same slf4j.version property variable. So, I don't know why the issue persists. I'll keep on researching.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the dependency for the slf4j api:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

This defines the api (interfaces) for slf4j and the other dependencies implement the api.

I recommend using logback as the implementation:  http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html

Here is the complete config to use slf4j with logback:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Finally, you need to add this to your logback.xml to have jul directed through slf4j:

```
<!-- support for jul through logback: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#LevelChangePropagator -->
<contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator"/>
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said but the same error persists. I added the dependencies to the pom and I created the logback-xml and logback-access.xml files but the same error persists. I don't know anymore what to do.

Comment: If you have the right dependencies in your pom, then they must not be getting into your application.  How are you running your app?

Answer (score 0):

I found in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ex the following files 
slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar

So, I remove these in favor of those installed by maven in the repository (.../.m2/repository) thus the problem was solved.